# How to use select statement inside SUM function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which looks like this.

```
ID      |    Block     |    Flats  |    Ammount  |    Balance  |
1       |      1       |      GF-1 |    1000     |      500    |
2       |      1       |      GF-2 |    1000     |      500    |
3       |      2       |      GF-1 |    1000     |      500    |
4       |      2       |      GF-2 |    1000     |      1000   |
5       |      2       |      GF-2 |    1000     |      0      |
```

I want to execute sum query on this. I have tried

```
Select distinct A.Block,(Select Sum(Ammount) from t1 where block = A.block),(select Sum(Balance) from t1 where block = A.block) from t1 A
```

This query is working fine but its summing balance to 2500 but as ID 4 & 5 are of same Flat so I want it to sum latest of balance which should be 1500. I have tried to put a select statement inside sum function but that doesn't work . So how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the most recent `id` for each `block`/`flats` combo first (using `row_number()`) and then aggregate:

```
Select t1.Block, sum(amount)
from (select t1.*,
             row_number() over (partition by block, flats order by id desc) as seqnum
      from t1
     ) t1
where seqnum = 1
group by t1.Block;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want to `SUM()` `group by block` like

```
select Block, sum(amount) totalamount,
sum(case when balance <> 0 then balance end) totalbalance
from t1
group by Block;
```

Comment: It's working fine but the problem is still the same. Its giving me sum of 2500 but I want it to give me 1500 as GF-2 has 2 entries and in second entry its balance became 0. I want it to include latest entry in in sum function.

Comment: Incorrect syntax near ')'. Sorry m not very good at SQL to fix that syntax myself. The error is at 2nd Sum's finishing bracket

Comment: still its adding that 1000.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below query

```
Select A.Block, Sum(A.Ammount), Sum(A.Balance)
from t1 A group by A.Flats order by A.ID;
```

Order by clause is used to sort with respect to ID

Comment: Column 'A.Block' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `SUM(DISTINCT ...)`

```
select Block, sum(DISTINCT amount) totalamount,
sum(DISTINCT case when balance <> 0 then balance end) totalbalance
from t1
group by Block;
```